# Read a file from an unknown location?

Tags: c#, readfile

I have got this read file code from microsoft

```
@"C:\Users\computing\Documents\mikec\assignment2\task_2.txt"
```

That works fine when im working on it, but when i am to hand in this assignment my lecturer isn't going to have the same directory as me.

So i was wondering if there is a way to read it from just the file the program is held in?.

I was thinking i could add it as a resource but im not sure if that is the correct way for the assignment it is meant to allow in any file.

Thanks

Comment: maybe is just me, but I really didn't get what's your trouble...

Comment: Why not just a `FileBrowserDialog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the path - this will read file from the working directory of the program.

Just `@"task_2.txt"` will do.

**UPDATE**: Please note that method won't work in some circumstances. If your lecturer uses some automated runner (script, application whatsoever) to verify your app then @ken2k's solution will be much more robust.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov But his question states that it is

Comment: Then it's not going to work, of course. I just suggested one possible way to overcome the issue.

Comment: This won't always work. What if the application is started from another location? `Environment.CurrentDirectory` could not be the physical location of the application.

Comment: @ken2k True. But I very much doubt that application which is just a lecturer's assignment will change its working directory programmatically.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Yes, but the use case that might reasonably occur it that the application is started from cmd.exe from another location (thus specifying the current directory at startup).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a file from the directory the program is in, then use

```
using System.IO;
...
string myFileName = "file.txt";
string myFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, myFileName);
```

EDIT:
More generic solution for non-winforms applications:

```
string myFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), myFileName);
```

Comment: Application.StartupPath might not be the same as the documents folder. The application could be deployed for example in Program Files.

Comment: You're right, but I don't think the OP wants specifically to use Documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a command line application, you should take the file name as a command line argument instead of using a fixed path. Something along the lines of;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args == null || args.Length != 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parameters are not ok, usage: ...");
        return;
    }

    string filename = args[0];

...
```

...should let you get the filename from the command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) method to get the documents folder of the current user:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

and to exemplify:

```
string myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string file = Path.Combine(myDocuments, @"mikec\assignment2\task_2.txt");
// TODO: do something with the file like reading it for example
string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Comment: He asked for the same place the program is held in, not my documents

Answer (score 0):

Use the relative path.

you can put your file inside the folder where your application resides.
you can use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() method to get the current folder of the application in. if you put your files inside a sub folder you can use 
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\subfolderName\"

```
File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\fileName.extension")


StreamReader file = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + ""));
            string fileTexts = file.ReadToEnd();
```