# How to read data from a text file if the file location is not known in c#?

Tags: c#, file

This question have been asked earlier in StackOverFlow and answers are also marked in that post. But sadly the solution provided in 
[Read a file from an unknown location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861854/read-a-file-from-an-unknown-location) does not solve my problem.
I am building a website and need to read data from a text file. The actual location of the file in my pc is: `C:\Developments\TestProject\PettyCashSolution\PettyCashWeb\DataFile.txt` and I
have tried below solutions from above link with no luck.

```
string sString = string.Empty;
string sStr = "";
StreamReader oStreamReader;
try
{
```

**Try1**

```
sStr = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "DataFile.txt");
```

**This returns below:**
`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\pettycashweb\af7f0870\c5ac294a\DataFile.txt`

**Try2**

```
sStr = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "DataFile.txt");
```

**This returns below:**
Compile Error: The name "Application" does not exist in the current context

**Try3**

```
oStreamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\DataFile.txt"));
```

**This returns below:**
Exception: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\DataFile.txt'

```
oStreamReader = new StreamReader(sStr);
sString = oStreamReader.ReadLine();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Please also advice what should I do so that after publishing the web in server (iis) the read data from text file will work properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get application path by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Your code must be like this

`sStr = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "DataFile.txt");`

Comment: Great, It works, Thanks. Just one more thing, will this approach work like now after hosting the web in server?

Comment: yes it will work when you publish your code to server. your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
```

then append string according to it.