# Giving path of a file in C#

Tags: c#, file-handling

I want to open a ***xxx.txt file kept on desktop*** of my Computer but the program gives an

error **Parser error unrecognized escape sequence '\D'**. I am trying to give the path of the

file as **"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\xxx.txt"** .

*Am i giving the path in a right way or is there any other way to give it*

Comment: try this `"C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/xxx.txt"` if it helps

Comment: pls check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083543/how-to-read-data-from-a-text-file-if-the-file-location-is-not-known-in-c

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in C# strings. It is used for special characters, such as line break (`\n`). To write a literal `\` you have to quote with another `\`:

```
string myFileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\xxx.txt";
```

An alternative is to disable quoting for the string with the `@` character:

```
string myFileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\xxx.txt";
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this path:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "xxx.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to access a file in my project, so the folder 'lib' which contains all the files i need, i placed this folder in the 'bin' folder of my project, and now i can access any file i need from lib folder.
In code path i used is as follows:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("..\\lib\\myFile.src");
```

Works well! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your path to `C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\xxx.txt`.

Answer (score -7):

Try to use **C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop/xxx.txt**

Instead of C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\xxx.txt