# Autoplay video on windows form

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

i am new to  .net  i am having trouble playing videos automatically.  I would be showing different textboxes here but i want the video to autplay without any  buttons

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace ThinkQDisplay
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Users\Ramrod\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ThinkQDisplay\ThinkQDisplay\sample.avi";
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps telling it is an unrecognized escape sequence. Also I would like to have a separate form (form2). Where I can choose what to play here on form 1. Is it also possible to have it looped?

Comment: Think on what an "escape sequence" would be in a string.

Comment: [Giving path of a file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10083671/205233) and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+unrecognized+escape+sequence+path) for this error message.

Comment: yeah i included the ; but it still says the name file does not exist in the current context  even though i added  using WMPLib;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving path of a file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083651/giving-path-of-a-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"C:\Users\Ramrod\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ThinkQDisplay\ThinkQDisplay\sampler.avi";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = true;
    }
}
```

}